# android phone freeze during the asynctask download

Tags: android, android-asynctask

i have done a code that will download the file from internet. but the problem is my phone will freeze(no response) until the download is done. the phone im using is Xperia Arc S and Galaxy S2. anyway to solve this?

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.staffchoices);       

        MyI = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MaxAppsAct.class);
        MyPI = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, MyI, 0);
        MyNM = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MaxAppsAct.class);
        final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);

        notification = new Notification(R.drawable.logo, "Downloading...", System.currentTimeMillis());
        notification.flags = notification.flags | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
        notification.contentView = new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.staffchoices);
        notification.contentIntent = pendingIntent;
        notification.contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.imgIcon, R.drawable.save);
        notification.contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.tvText, "Downloading...");
        notification.contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.pbStatus, 100, progress, false);
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(42, notification);

        String url = "http://www.domainURL.com/3d.png";
        new DownloadFileAsync().execute(url);
        }

        public class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
            }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... aurl) {
            int count;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
                URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
                conexion.connect();

                int lengthOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
                Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Lenght of file: " + lengthOfFile);

                File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MaxApps");
                boolean success = false;
                if (!folder.exists()) {
                    success = folder.mkdirs();
                }
                if (!success) {
                } else {
                }

                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/MaxApps/3d.png");

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                long total = 0;

                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                publishProgress((int)((total*100)/lengthOfFile));               
                output.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                output.flush();
                output.close();
                input.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {}

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {          
            notification.contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.pbStatus, 100, progress[0], false);
            notificationManager.notify(42, notification);
            }

        protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
            notificationManager.cancel(42);

            Notification MyN = new Notification(); MyN.icon = R.drawable.logo1;
            MyN.tickerText = "Download Complete";
            MyN.number = 1;
            MyN.setLatestEventInfo (getApplicationContext(), "Application Title", "Application Description", MyPI);

            MyNM.notify(1, MyN);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say the "phone will freeze" does that include if you hit the home button nothing will happen?  Also what version of android are you running on the phone?

Comment: What happens when you increase the buffer (the byte array) size to a larger value, say 16*1024 (16K) ?

Comment: @Rajesh, thx for the advice, the performance is much better now, but it's not as smooth as expected. i plan to do somthing  like this, but it's not responding. if (total % (lengthOfFile / 20) == 0) { 
     publishProgress((int)((total*100)/lengthOfFile));
    }

Comment: @mikeIsrael no, no have respond at all. using 2.3.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The performance bottleneck seems to be the frequency at which the `publishProgress` is called. You should devise a way by which you publish the progress less often, without affecting the user experience.

Suggestions:

1. Increase the buffer size to a reasonable value like 16K or 32K
2. Change the progress publishing mechanism as follows:

   ```
   while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
       total += count;
       int progressPercent = (int) ((total*100)/lengthOfFile);
       if(progressPercent % 20 == 0){  //publish progress on completion of every 20%
           publishProgress(progressPercent);
       }
       output.write(data, 0, count);
   }
   ```